# set variable to cmd.exe

Tags: c++, windows, shell, variables, cmd

Greeting earthmen,

Here is my question:

How can I create a program which sets variable to current session of cmd.exe  e.g.

```
c:\> set myvar
Environment variable myvar not defined
c:\>myexe.exe
c:>set myvar
myvar=myvalue
```

The only similar topic that I've found is this -

[How can I change Windows shell (cmd.exe) environment variables from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774047/how-can-i-change-windows-shell-cmd-exe-environment-variables-from-c+c)

But I didn't get a single word from this:

> There is a way... Just inject your
>   code into parent process and call
>   SetEnvironmentVariableA inside cmd's
>   process memory. After injecting just
>   free the allocated memory.

While C/C++ is not my "native" language I've felt myself completely lost when I've searched google with "c++ inject code" and etc...  Is there an article where I can get more info about this.

BTW now I'm using one a little bit stupid workaround.As the setting a variable to

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment

and

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

is  comparatively easy I'm just recording similar variable to the registry:

```
load.temp.vars=set myvar1=myval1&set myvar2=myval2& ....
```

and then just call %load.temp.vars% and it will be executed as a command:

```
c:/>%load.temp.vars%
c:/>set myvar1
myvar1=myval1
```

It works fine bu it's not good enough  for me :)

Live long and prosper,
\\//_

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the Environment of a parent process in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263005/is-it-possible-to-change-the-environment-of-a-parent-process-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article: [Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx#section_3).

Also you probably will need a handle to your parent process (to determine the target process whose environment to change). A way to get it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185254/how-can-a-win32-process-get-the-pid-of-its-parent).

Just keep in mind that injection may not work, depending on user account privileges, and also that some especially paranoid antivirus solutions may frown upon it.

Answer (score 2):

There are very easy way to do this **without any tricks**.

You should write a small program `myexe.exe` which produce a simple output (console output) like following:

```
SET myvar=Some value
```

then you start your program with the following steps:

```
myexe.exe >%TEMP%\t.cmd
call %TEMP%\t.cmd
del %TEMP%\t.cmd
```

Now in the current `cmd.exe` which started myexe.exe exist the environment variable `myvar` and it has the value `Some value`. Is it not exactly what you want?

The way is extrem simple and it works on all versions of Windows (and not only Windows). So it is my recommendation for you.

Comment: your example as posted will only work on Windows. The method, however, is universal (if you assume everyone has some shell interpreter like Bash).

Comment: I mean of cause the method (or the way)

Comment: @Johannes: Every person can have his own opinion. If you prefer to produce output with a value only than you have to write more code in batch which is VERY slow, please do this. Moreover in a real situation you need set not one, but a set of environment variables. In this case the output of several lines "SET myvar=Some value" is the best solution which I know. I had the first experience in solving of such problem in MS DOS using undocumented but well known features. Later I tested different ways and find this way which I find as the best one. If you do prefer another way, please use it.