# Source .bat file script variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tivoli-work-scheduler

I am looking for a method in PowerShell to source the environment variables from running a .bat file script into the Env: provider.

Is there an equivalent to twa_env.cmd that will setup the environment for TWS correctly in PowerShell?

I can start a cmd.exe shell, CALL twa_env.cmd, then start PowerShell. That seems to work. What I cannot yet do is to start a PowerShell shell, run twa_env.cmd, and bring the new variable settings back into the PowerShell Env:.

Comment: Yeah: `& tws_env.bat`.  Environment variables will be created in the powershell session.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - That would be really nice. In your experience, does it work? Start a PowerShell console, run `& tws_env.bat`, then run conman or composer. Is that working for you?

Comment: I don't have it installed at the moment, but execute the batch script in a powershell session and run `Get-Command -Name co*`

Comment: Are you asking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711294/in-powershell-after-changing-to-cmd-unable-to-call-a-bat-file-through-a-batch-sc/42729430#42729430?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - Yes, that answer is -very- close. It is almost identical to what I was trying, but I was using `Invoke-Command`. It still does not create a working environment for TWS. I am still investigating.

Comment: Why do you need `Invoke-Comand`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I source variables from a .bat file into a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077820/how-can-i-source-variables-from-a-bat-file-into-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell can run a `cmd.exe` shell script (batch file), but it (naturally) has to execute it using `cmd.exe`. The problem is that when the `cmd.exe` executable closes, the environment variables it sets don't propagate to the calling PowerShell session.

The workaround is to "capture" the environment variables set in the `cmd.exe` session and manually propagate them to PowerShell after the batch file finishes. The following `Invoke-CmdScript` PowerShell function can do that for you:

```
# Invokes a Cmd.exe shell script and updates the environment.
function Invoke-CmdScript {
  param(
    [String] $scriptName
  )
  $cmdLine = """$scriptName"" $args & set"
  & $Env:SystemRoot\system32\cmd.exe /c $cmdLine |
    Select-String '^([^=]*)=(.*)$' |
    ForEach-Object {
      $varName = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
      $varValue = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
      Set-Item Env:$varName $varValue
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work. It was not working for me because the application -REQUIRES- administrator privs. I do not see why that would be needed, but I did not write the app. It also works with the `Invoke-Expression` I used. I will give you the check for this copy of the other answer.